# Using SharedPreferences only setText() works but append() does not

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, settext

I have a main activity which has two fragments and I am trying to pass some data which I want to append on above whatever texts is already on a edittext on the next fragment.

Activity with two separate Tabs:

[image]

**The following works fine**:

Fragment #1:

```
String y = "TEST 1";
SharedPreferences prefs;  // shared preferences
prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("spa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("someId", y);
editor.commit();
```

Fragment #2:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;  // shared preferences
prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("spa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String someId=prefs.getString("someId","");
showLog.setText(someId + "\n HERE"); //this overwrites the text and is multiline
```

What I am looking to do is I want the showLog to append above what's already there.

My showLog is the following:

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/showLog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Nothing to display"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="12"
            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:gravity="top" />
```

For example:

`showLog` already starts out with having "THIS IS A TEST" in the textbox
When the `SharedPreference` is called, the `showLog` should display the following:

```
TEST 1
 HERE
THIS IS A TEST
```

But that's not happening. I tried using `.append()` which didn't have any affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do now, you might want to try:

```
int start = showLog.getSelectionStart();
int end = showLog.getSelectionEnd();
String toIns = someId + "\n HERE";
showLog.getText().replace(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end), toIns, 0, toIns.length());
```

Technically it's not appending, rather replacing the end of the string with new text.

**EDIT:** in light of the new issue arising, here are my edits to your project, let me know if there's anything wrong still.

**My edited version is on the right, original on the left**

[CurrentTrip.java](http://www.diffchecker.com/y8rpvbpm)

[DisplayTrip.java](http://www.diffchecker.com/36h2tdjk)

What I'm doing with the text might not be exactly what you want, so make sure to let me know if it's not.

**EDIT 2:** And to delete the stored values:

```
final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

**EDIT 3:** Having understood exactly what it is you want to do, here's one way to do it by storing the last trip added, and keeping track of the text you need in your TextView.

```
prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("spa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// Find the string we want
String someId = prefs.getString("someId","");
final Editor editor = prefs.edit();
// To stop a trip being added in onResume etc.
if(someId != prefs.getString("previous-trip", "")){
    showLog.setText(someId + prefs.getString("previous", ""));
} else {
    // Without this else, we'd have a blank box again
    showLog.setText(prefs.getString("previous", ""));
}
// Store the latest trip that was added
editor.putString("previous-trip", someId);
// Store everything that's in the box so far for next time
editor.putString("previous", showLog.getText().toString());
// Commit to the prefs
editor.commit();
```

Comment: @SiKni8 Do you have your project hosted anywhere?

Comment: I can zip it and put it ob GitHub

Comment: @SiKni8 If in a while you're still stuck, put it on GH and add a link to the project in your OP and we can take a look.

Comment: Added the link above.

Comment: @SiKni8 Ok got it. Give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: One more thing if you can look at for me... If I enter something in tab one and switch to tab 2 and come back to tab 1 the information disappears. How do I fix it?

Comment: @SiKni8 Is there any chance you can quickly use Paint to create a quick image of exactly what you're wanting to happen? Think I have it but not entirely sure. :p

Comment: Lol... I left my desk. I can do it tomorrow for you?

Comment: I see the answer and thank you. I will check as soon as I am able to, tomorrow. And will update you on my findings :)

Comment: I see that the new code is saving two variable, But I do not see the variable being called in the next Fragment or am I missing something?

Comment: @SiKni8 It's not called in the next Fragment, it's called upon return to the same Fragment from the new Fragment (storing your data as asked).

Comment: Aaahhhh I see... How would I call those data in Display class?

Comment: @SiKni8 Exactly the same as it's called in CurrentTrip :)

Comment: So I am hinting its like using session in PHP? When does the variable clear out? Can I do it so the variable never clears out unless the Clear button is pressed in the Display class?

Comment: Also, one last issue (promise... Maybe). If I switch between Tabs the information I entered in Current class goes blank. Any way to prevent that?

Comment: Kinda, I'm pretty sure it only vanishes when your data is cleared. And is it not already doing that? It was for me, with those changes.

Comment: The clear button just clears out the show log text to "" but doesn't clear out value store in sharedpreference. I guess that's fine for now. Maybe in the future I can do other cool stuff.

Comment: Oh my bad, misunderstood what you meant. Updated answer :)

Comment: I will add that for Clear button. Thanks. I'll test out the app changes tmrw and report finding. You have been a great help. Wish there was a way to add people here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34411/discussion-between-zackehh9lives-and-sikni8)

Comment: It's not working. I will use Paint and show you what I am looking to achieve

Comment: @SiKni8 Ok, but let's keep all additions to this in the question chat :) I've got the notification enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to get then you should be able to do

```
String text = showLog.getText().toString();
showLog.setText(someId + "\n HERE" + text);
```

If you already have text in it then you just get that text and after opening up your `SharedPreference` put it all in with the original text last.

[Intent extras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

In first `Activity`

```
String someText = someTextString;
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key", someText);   // add some extra to the Intent to pass to next Activity
startActivity(i);
```

In `SecondActivity`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String myText = intent.getStringExtra("key");  // use same key value used in first Activity
```

Comment: Hmmmm... didn't think  it that way. Let me try it out. Thanks. (Update: Now it just sets the text, rather than Appending it)

Comment: It will set the text but it will put your new variables first then your original text that was in `showLog`. I guess I'm not sure exactly what you're after. Can you clarify what is happening now and what you want?

Comment: Fragment #1 has a button which, once clicked, takes the value of the edittext and sends it to Fragment #2 to be appended to showLog. After I made the edit as per your suggestion (which works btw with a minor issue) All it does it overwrite with new information that is saved in `someId` rather than appending it.

Comment: So the original text isn't showing after doing it this way? Is `showLog` the `View` that already has text that you want appended to?

Comment: `showLog.setText( "SOMETEXT" + showLog.getText() );` was working for me when I wasn't using `SharePreferences` or `Fragments`.

Comment: @SiKni8 And that doesn't work in a Fragment? I don't quite understand why this answer doesn't work for you, what difference does setting the text make to appending it if there's the same outcome?

Comment: Nope. Can I send you my Project, maybe you can take a look?

Comment: Maybe because I am changing Activity? I added an image of what's happening

Comment: If you are changing `Activities` then you need to send the text in an `extra` with the `Intent`. Also, you need to use `toString()` on the end of `getText()`

Comment: Would you be able to help me with `extra`?

Comment: @SiKni8 `startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), newClass.class)).putExtra("string", yourstring));`

Comment: I updated with an example of using `extra` as well as a link to the docs. Hope that helps

Comment: If I have `String y = "send this"` How would I use the `putExtra()` and `getExtra()`?

Comment: @SiKni8 `intent.putExtra("y", "send this");` and in your new Activity `getIntent().getStringExtra("y");`

Comment: I have one issue with the updated example and that's I have been experiencing with all the examples I found.
I have the following: `Intent i = new Intent(Current.this, Display.class);` and I get an error: `The constructor Intent(Current, Display) is undefined`

Comment: Is `Current` the name of the `Activity` you are currently in and `Display.class` is the `Activity` that you want to start?

Comment: Current is started by `public class CurrentTrip extends Fragment {` and yes Current is the class I have the textbox and Display is where I want the showLog to take the value and append above what's already there.

Comment: @SiKni8 You're using `Fragments` right? If so the first argument to the `Intent` has to be `getActivity()`. `new Intent(getActivity(), Display.class);`

Comment: So the sending Fragment isn't showing any errors but on the receiving Fragment for the following line, `Intent intent = getIntent();` I am getting the following error: `The method getIntent() is undefined for the type Display`

Comment: @SiKni8 Is Display a fragment too? If so you access `getIntent()` from `getActivity().getIntent()`

Comment: Thanks @Zackehh9lives. I am doing to give it a try now.

Comment: @SiKni8 I just realised, if you're trying to pass between Fragments, going via Intent is a bad way to do things. Posting your project would be a valid option right now :p

Comment: LOL... uploading it now :)

Comment: Added the link above.

Comment: One more thing if you can look at for me... If I enter something in tab one and switch to tab 2 and come back to tab 1 the information disappears. How do I fix it? –

Answer (score 1):

About the part where you need to display the `String`:

```
// From what you have given, the TextView `showLog` is already displaying some text
// and you want to place another another String in front of it(prepend)

showLog.setText(stringToAdd + showLog.getText());

// "stringToAdd" is the string you trying to pass between activities(or fragments)
```